# Distance of point from a particular line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The number of  points  on the  line $3x + 4y = 5$,  which are  at  a  distance  of $sec^2\theta+2cosec^2\theta$  ,$\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ from the  point $(1,  3)$,  is
(1) 1

(2) 2

(3) 3

(4) infinite

My approach is as follow the least distance of $3x+4y=5$ from the point $(1,3)$ is $2$ which is perpendicular distance. The point from $3x+4y=5$ from the point $(1,3)$ may not be perpendicular. The distance $sec^2\theta+2cosec^2\theta$ is always greater than $2$ so we need to find the number of points valid for $sec^2\theta+2cosec^2\theta$ which I am not able to find.

Comment: Is the answer supposed to depend on $\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sec^2\theta+2\csc^2\theta$ is unbounded in the positives, so there are infinitely many points that can satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}+\frac{2}{\sin^2\theta}=(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}+\frac{2}{\sin^2\theta}\right)\geq(1+\sqrt2)^2,$$ which gives a range of $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}+\frac{2}{\sin^2\theta}$: $\left[(1+\sqrt2)^2,+\infty\right)$ 
 and there are infinitely many such points.

Comment: if the minimum is $(1+\sqrt{2})^2$, the range starts with it, does not it?

Comment: should not the range be: $[(1+\sqrt{2})^2,+\infty)$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll fix it. Thank you, dear @farruhota !

Comment: no problem, good method, +1